# Can I create a private network that is user independent in docker?

Tags: docker

So we have bunch of containers on a system and we want to be able to start/stop them from various User ID (Linux) with docker-compose.

In the docker compose we create a private network so the containers can talk to each other:

```
networks:
  our_app:
    driver: bridge
```

But when we use docker-compose the network is create as "userid_our_app".
Is there not a way to create a network across all users in the compose file?

Comment: Composes generally chooses names for containers, networks, and volumes so that objects in different Compose projects won't conflict with each other.  This shouldn't usually be a problem, and you can usually use `docker-compose` commands to manage these objects (especially containers) using their Compose names.  Is there a reason the non-Compose Docker name of this network matters?

Comment: Hi, the problem is that User A Start the containers. Then User B ant to restart one container and it will not be able to connect as the network seems to be user specific.

Comment: Docker doesn't have any notion of "user".  Any user can start, stop, create, or delete any container.  You can also fairly easily use `docker run` to root the entire host.  Do you have a more specific example of a setup where you have two different Compose setups, and one is interfering with the other?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a network using the docker network create command, then refer to it as default network in the docker-compose manifests, like:

```
networks:
  default:
    name: our_app_network
    external: true
```